# setState not updating font awesome icon

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, setstate

I'm trying to dynamically render font awesome icon in myself written checkbox component. When I'm trying to update state of a  with font awesome icon after clicking on it it is not updating. I've tried to move render to separate function and tried to use react-fontawesome but nothing helps. The state is updating but font awesome icons are the same svg code in html.

```
...
state = {
 checked: this.props.checked
}

toggleCheck = () => {
  this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });  
};

render () {

  const iconUnchecked = 'far fa-square';
  const iconChecked = 'fas fa-check-square';
  const iconClass = this.state.checked ? iconChecked : iconUnchecked;

  return (
    <span onClick={this.toggleCheck}>
      <i className={iconClass} />
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: i think you miss type here `const iconUnchecked = 'far fa-square'` must be `const iconUnchecked = 'fas fa-square';`

Comment: The problem is still the same

Comment: First of all change `iconClass` to `let`, because you want to change it in future.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I understood the font awesome js manipulates DOM and React manipulates virtual DOM. When font awesome js doing its own stuff React can't rerender it after state change. Im still on React 15 and maybe it's not the issue in React 16. I just found a solution for me to put every   with font awesome in a div with unique key. This way React see that div must change because key was changed.

Comment: The key here is to put the `key` prop on the containing element, _not_ on the element that has the font-awesome class applied to it. `<button key='unique'><i className={'fas' + condition ? 'fa-eye' : 'fa-edit'} /></button>`

Comment: yup worked nicely, you can actually use the this.state.checked as unique key

Answer (score 1):

Try that one https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/30533/

For me seems to work

Check exactly jsfiddle it works, but not a snippet. Snippet is just to satisfy editor.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: this.props.checked
    }
    this.toggleCheck = this.toggleCheck.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleCheck() {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });  
  }
  
  render() {
    const iconUnchecked = 'far fa-square';
   const iconChecked = 'fas fa-check-square';
   let iconClass = this.state.checked ? iconChecked : iconUnchecked;

    return (
      <span onClick={this.toggleCheck}>
        <i className={iconClass} />
      </span>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same trouble. As 200Ok mentioned it correctly, svg--inline-fa is not a virtual DOM so it never gets updated. The best way to solve the problem is to wrap the font awesome elements that would contain the decisive classes.